# Automatically labeling layers according to raster characteristics

Tags: raster, labeling, classification, aerial-photography

The question is oriented more towards end user and came up during the preparation of field maps, which have to show previously mapped biotopes and their ID on an aerial image. The map is used to rework the old polygon layers according to the current situation in the field.

The problem is that with any automatic labelling method used in the QGIS label toolbox, the labels still hide relevant areas on the printed map which are needed for orientation or for spotting potentially relevant areas or changes of vegetation patterns.

I wonder whether there is a possibility to provide rules to QGIS to place labels of a polygon layer at indicated areas according to a raster image.
The relevant background would be an aerial image, used at a 1:5000 scale in the printed map.

The labels have to be applied according to a couple of tricky rules:

- the labels should not overlay distinct features in the aerial photo, e.g. single trees, small colourshifts in grassland that indicate change in vegetation pattern, small bushes, rivers, small areas with open water, ...
- they are allowed to be placed on e.g. forests, housed areas, fields, so to say either very homogeneous regions or assigned areas which are of no interest
- they should not overlap with each other
- they should be as close to the polygon as possible
- if the aerial photo indicates homogeneity **and** the polygon is big enough to incorporate the label, the label should be placed inside the polygon

I have some programming skills in R and could get help with python, too.
But I have no clue whether that is possible at all.

My first idea was to try to classify the rasters based on areas where labeling is possible and where it is not. This would need a bit of a training of an algorithm I guess, as the rules are probably a bit implicit.

But this can only help if labelling according to another dataset, in this case a raster, is possible at all.

Comment: Is this a one time task? If so, you may simply use the label toolbar to move your labels around.

Comment: if you are able to reclassify your raster in two category ("ok for labeling" and "no label allowed") you just have to vectorise the no label area and use the resulting polygon layer as a blocking layer. the hard part really is to classify the aerial image...

Comment: Thanks, Erik! You are right, if it would be a one time task, this would be the easiest way. Unfortunately, it has to be done several times a year..

Comment: @ J.R. I didn't think about the possibility of a blocking layer, so thanks for that! The problem is, I am not sure if that would work in areas where labels have to be placed on unconvenient spots due to sheer lack of space and/or a high number of polygons clustered together... I don't know if you can work by prioritising a blocking layer, if... so I guess I will wait to see if further approaches are mentioned and try this one a bit later.